# C# Panel.BackgroundImage + transparent Controls = flickering?

Tags: c#, transparency, panel, picturebox

I've got a `Panel` with a jpg `BackgroundImage` (with `BackgroundImageLayout = Stretch`).
On the panel it's `Controls` I add some `PictureBoxes` with a PNG which has transparent borders. Displaying this doesn't give any problems, but moving (the boxes are draggable) the `PictureBoxes` does.

The result is that the moving `PictureBox` "disturbs" the `BackgroundImage` and slows down performance. The faster I drag the box, the more it disturbs the `BackgroundImage`, and vice versa.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b367a457.aspx

All you need to do is turn double-buffering on using the property on the Form.