# Drawing an image onto a Panel control gives artefacts when resizing

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, onpaint

Currently I'm trying to do what I thought would be a simple task:

**Draw an image onto the full area of a [`Panel` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx)** in Windows Forms. (Please ignore for the moment that I could use the [`BackgroundImage` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimage.aspx))

The image to draw looks like this:

[image]

I.e. a yellow box with an 1 pixel blue frame around.

To draw, I'm using the `Paint` event of the `Panel` control:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Resources.MyImage, panel1.ClientRectangle);
}
```

This looks fine when initially displaying the form:

[image]

When resizing the form (and the docked panel, too), it either cuts the edges when being made smaller...

[image]

...or it draws artefacts, when being made larger:

[image]

I'm pretty sure that there is going on something rather simple and straight-forward but I really cannot understand the reason.

Since I'm ignoring the `ClipRectangle` and always draw everything, I thought the image would be scaled all the time.

**My questions are:**

- What is the reason for the artefacts? (I *love* to understand this!)
- What do I have to do in order to get rid of the artefacts? (beside calling `Invalidate` on each resize)

**Update, SOLUTION:**

Thanks to [Ryan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9751409/107625), I was able to find an acceptable solution. Basically I derived a class from `Panel`, did an override of `OnPaintBackground` and did *not* call the base method. Last, I added the following code to the constructor of my derived panel:

```
base.DoubleBuffered = true;

SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);

UpdateStyles();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970196/c-sharp-panel-backgroundimage-transparent-controls-flickering

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the artefacts is that the entire surface isn't redrawn when the form is resized; only the necessary parts are. The generally best solution is what you don't want to do, calling `Invalidate` on each resize. However, if this is in fact your situation, just use a `PictureBox` instead. If it's not, you might consider overriding `OnPaint` in your form instead, and using `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true)` to do this automatically.

Comment: Any chance to reduce the flickering when calling `Invalidate`? (I do think this comes from the background being drawn first) Maybe turning of background drawing/filling?

Comment: @UweKeim: You'll need to enable double-buffering; subclass `Panel`, use `OnPaint` instead of handling `Paint`, and set the `DoubleBuffered` property to `true`.