# Flickering View in C# WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, view, window-resize

There is flickering whenever I resize or hide a panel/tablelayoutpanel/button etc., also when resizing the window.

How can I prevent the flickering?

[image: Flicker on resize]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do my WinForms controls flicker and resize slowly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690426/why-do-my-winforms-controls-flicker-and-resize-slowly). Also [Drawing an image onto a Panel control gives artefacts when resizing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751373/drawing-an-image-onto-a-panel-control-gives-artefacts-when-resizing)

Comment: My problem is not only with resizing. If for example i will try to hide one panel and show another one, I am confronted with the same problem.

Comment: WinForms is not very performant platform when it comes to heavy GUI lifting. And there is not much you can do except what has already been suggested. You may try to turn some controls into WPF controls and use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215(v=vs.110).aspx, but that is a lot of work and has issues of its own .

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please tell me, what do you proposed except the winform? How i could create a windows "template" software with windows, buttons etc?

Comment: You can try [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970268(v=vs.110).aspx) but it is not an easy way. Also there can be some third-party controls(telerik, devexpress) with similar look and better performance.

Comment: @EugenePodskal WinForms is performant enough it you play by the rules.
@ NickName Do you have the source code of the controls or are these 'commercial'?

Comment: @Rudi Yes, if `you play by the rules`. Unfortunately "by the rules" usually means that it is relatively difficult to achieve both acceptable performance and fancy control rendering at the same time.